# how to redirect to another page when using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a form In their it has a cancel button. when that button is clicked a confirm box will appear and ask whether user needs to leave the page then i need to redirect the page .I'm using codeigniter and I did this but it is redirects to same page.I don't know why? can anyone help me?

View(busineeRateView.php)

```
 <?php $Vehicleid=$details['id']; ?>
<input type="submit" name="cancelreview" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="CANCEL" onClick="return cancelConfirm();">

<script>
    function cancelConfirm() {
         job = confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel and leave this page?");
         if (job == true) {
            window.location.href = "http://localhost/ci/adpreview_ctrl/getad_preview/".$Vehicleid; 
            return true;
         }
    }
</script>
```

controller

```
public function loadReviewPage($vehicleid){


$data=array();
$data['details']['id']=$vehicleid;

$this->load->view('pages/templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/businessRateView',$data);
    $this->load->view('pages/templates/footer');
```

}

Comment: Maybe you should research firstly and most foremost about client-side programming and server-side programming. You have merged the both together, 1 being PHP and the other, JS. If you do in-fact want to put a PHP variable into JS, you can use conditional formatting but the variable will be converted to HTML and will not be able to be "picked up" or will not exist in JS. ie: `$Vehicle == "abc";` will only show as `abc` in JS. You need to wrap your `<?php ?>` tags round and echo it.

Comment: $Vehileid from where?

Comment: it's coming from a controller. I think because of that still it doesn't show the result. i took it like this in view.  <?php $Vehicleid=$details['id']; ?>  Is this wrong

Comment: Depending on how your JavaScript is being outputted, the `$Vehicleid` will not exist in the current Scope unless defined in PHP. You'll need to follow @devnull 's answer and append your PHP tags around the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you `return true` from the event handler, the submit button submits the form.

Since that comes after the `location` assignment, it overwrites it.

Submitting a form will reload the current page (assuming form doesn't have an `action` attribute and the submitted data doesn't cause the server to return a different page).

Don't use a submit button. Your JavaScript is doing little more than simulating a link, so use a real link.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
   href="http://localhost/ci/adpreview_ctrl/getad_preview/$Vehicleid"
   onclick="return cancelConfirm();">
    Cancel
</a>
```

and

```
function cancelConfirm(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel and leave this page?");
}
```

NB: You seem to have left some PHP in your example. Make sure you express your URL in valid HTML/JS.

Comment: Good spot, I didn't even see the repetition of the `return` - Vote Up.

Answer (score 2):

this line is confusing:

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost/ci/adpreview_ctrl/getad_preview/".$Vehicleid;
```

Seems you mix javascript and php. Concatenating strings in JS is done with  +, not . which is php syntax. and php variables like $Vehicleid are not accessible directly in JS. Try to use a php block for that. like:

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost/ci/adpreview_ctrl/getad_preview/" + "<?= $Vehicleid; ?>";
```

Comment: for those who suggested <?php echo($Vehicleid); ?> it is not neccessary because <?= $Vehicleid ?> is a shorter variant and not to confuse with <? ?>

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you use the wrong operation. You should use '+' instead of '.' in javascript string operation. '.' is used in php:)

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost/ci/adpreview_ctrl/getad_preview/" + $Vehicleid;
```

Comment: The answer from devnull is same idea, but he thought more carefully about how to combine php with javascript. So follow his answer please.